# Best way to select useful features using R software

Tags: r, feature-selection

I have a huge matrix (individuals X features with row.names as individuals numbers) and the corresponding segment in another vector of 1D (row.names are the same as in my huge matrix and the vector represent the segments associated).
I.E. :

```
row.names VAR1 VAR2 VAR3 VAR4 … VAR3000
    12     4    12    5   18      8
    58     6    13    19   3     10
```

for the huge matrix.
and:

```
row.names  x
    12     4
    58     2
```

for the segment representation (where x represent the individual' segment).

I have no a priori model and I want to select a subset of variables (variable/feature selection) in order to predict the segment using a minimal subset of variables. I didn't use biclustering technique to detect my classes but a simple-way one. Which technique would you recommend to :

1. select the most discriminative variables (lasso, elastic net) and why?
2. predict the segment from these variables.
3. predict multiple values in another similar matrix (same individuals, few predictors that have been selected). Is it possible in this case to use correlation matrix (or cov) to infer directly the values of predictors that are not known in the other matrix (not using the following method: predict the class, then fill the missing values with medoid values or cluster-mean values)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you are trying to predict x, based on VAR1-VAR3000?  Is x a numeric variable or is it a factor?

Comment: x is a class (i.e. 1~100)

Comment: I would maybe start with a multinomial regression in glmnet, since that will be pretty fast.  If you don't get good results, look at a RF/SVM/some other method of discrimination.  IMHO, you're going to have some trouble distinguishing 100 classes.

Answer (score 1):

One idea would be to use the [rfe](http://rgm2.lab.nig.ac.jp/RGM2/func.php?rd_id=caret:rfe) function in the [caret](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/index.html) package.  Use the option rfeControl = rfeControl(functions=rfFunctions) to calculate variable importance using a random forest.

The rfe algorithm is explained in detail in the [vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/vignettes/caretSelection.pdf):
[image: Alg 2]

If a random forest performs well on your dataset, this is usually a good way to improve it.  Or maybe the random forest alone gives you sufficiently accurate predictions.

You can also use the [glmnet](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/index.html) package to use the elastic net for regularization/selection.  This will be MUCH faster, and often performs quiet well.  If you've already got a glm model that you like, glmnet might improve it.

tl;dr: If a random forest works well on your data, try `rfe` with the `rfFuncs`.  If a linear model works well, try `glmnet`, or `rfe` with `lmFuncs`.

Comment: +1 for the pointers. Of note, backward elimination procedure for RF was proposed in Díaz-Uriarte and Alvarez de Andrés, [Gene selection and classification of microarray data using random forest](http://www.biomedcentral.com/1471-2105/7/3/abstract), BMC Bioinformatics 2006, 7:3, but see the [varSelRF](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/varSelRF/index.html) R package. It is far less computer-intensive than RFE-SVM.

Comment: @chl: Is there an R package for RFE-SVM?

Comment: Did you have time to look at the [pathClass](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pathClass/index.html) code I linked to in an earlier comment? Otherwise, I just found this one: [R implementation of the Support Vector Mahine Recursive Feature Extraction (SVM-RFE) Algorithm](http://www.uccor.edu.ar/paginas/seminarios/Software/SVM_RFE_R_implementation.pdf). Let me know how it goes.

Comment: @chl: I didn't see the pathClass code.  Thanks for the links